# Can I include flash content inside a silverlight app?

Tags: flash, silverlight

I have a silverlight application, which requires charts with printing. As silverlight does not support printing, I was thinking of including some flash charts inside my application. I know it sounds weird.... But is it possible?

Comment: cats and dogs, flash and silverlight, the end is neigh!

Comment: Yes, it sounds weird. Is generating the charts on the server (as PDF, for example) not an option? Anyway, good luck with your approach :)

Comment: Is there a good reason not to go with Flash for the whole application, as you obviously require features that Flash provides, but Silverlight doesn't (not to mentioned the broader userbase Flash is going to bring you)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey.. Check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1211511.aspx) .The second post talks about embedding flash in silverlight. Try asking in that thread.

But I doubt whether it possible because as grapefrult, in the comments, said they are cats and dogs ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to run flash content inside of Silverlight or vice-versa. However, it *is* possible to run both types of content on the same html page. You can even (I *think*) have them layered on top of each other using windowless controls. You can have them communicate via javascript. You could probably do something similar to solve the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Silverlight 4 That has Printing Support, Its finally released, the charts can be built using the Silverlight Toolkit.

Check this Link (for printing):
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#printing

Answer (score 0):

You may not run flash content within a Silverlight application.  They use two different plug-ins that don't interact with each other in that way.

I'm answering the main question in the subject.  I suggest another topic (if one doesn't already exist) for the printing issue.

Answer (score -1):

Silverlight 3 beta is now available. It allows you to write your own codec.

From the what's new in silverlight 3 doc:

> Extensible media format support: With the new Raw AV pipeline, Silverlight can easily support a wide variety of third-party codecs. Audio and video can be decoded outside the runtime and rendered in Silverlight, extending format support beyond the native codecs.

I think the problem with Silverlight natively supporting flash is copyright issues between adobe and microsoft, as far as i know.

Likely that someone will write a codec that you can just drop in to your app.